# S,T : V->V ker(S) is a subset of ker(TS)

Tags: linear-algebra

if T and S are both linear transformations from the vector space V -> V how can i prove or disprove that the ker(S) is a subset of ker(TS)
and is the oposite true? is ker(TS) a subset of ker (S)

Comment: What's about of consider the definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be showed directly that $\operatorname{ker} (S) \subset \operatorname{ker} (TS)$: For every $x \in \operatorname{ker} (S)$, we have $S x = 0$. Hence $TSx = T 0 = 0$, which means $x \in \operatorname{ker} (TS)$.

The  oposite is not true by just considering $S = I$, the identity operator and $T = 0$. In this case, $\operatorname{ker} (TS) = V$ and $\operatorname{ker} (S) = \{0\}$.